# Reactive.Linq.Observable locking tfs2012

Tags: system.reactive

We have an problem using the System.Reactive.Linq.Observable with a Team Foundation Server 2012. It keeps given the same error

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (3540): Unable to copy file "C:\Builds\11\MES_Projects\MESAdmin -
>   Plugin.CopyConfigData\Sources\3rdParty\Rx\2.1\Net40\System.Reactive.Linq.dll"
>   to "C:\Builds\11\MES_Projects\MESAdmin -
>   Plugin.CopyConfigData\Binaries\System.Reactive.Linq.dll". Access to
>   the path 'C:\Builds\11\MES_Projects\MESAdmin -
>   Plugin.CopyConfigData\Binaries\System.Reactive.Linq.dll' is denied.

And it's the same error on all builds. The code works perfectly both the source and the compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the file paths, it doesn't seem the dll itself is the problem. Something is keeping hold of the file preventing it being overwritten. Suggest you start with finding out what process has a hold of the file. Try using [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) or similar.

Are you running some tests that aren't exiting properly for example?